# How I extract some coloumn from text file using bash scripting

Tags: bash

I have one file as bellow and I want to format it as the result shown below, please I need your help. Thanks in advance. The file is so huge.

**File:**

```
X  1846      211L  33599.00  51209.001    1  4321
X  1846      211L  33599.00  51209.001  433  8641
X  1846      211L  33599.00  51209.001  865 12961
X  1846      211L  33599.00  51209.001 1297 17281
X  1846      221L  34031.00  52085.002    1  2211
X  1846      221L  34031.00  52085.002  222  4421
X  1846      221L  34031.00  52085.002  443  6631
X  1846      221L  34031.00  52085.002  664  8841
.....
X  1846     1001L  34023.00  51785.002    1  3711
X  1846     1001L  34023.00  51785.002  372  7421
X  1846     1001L  34023.00  51785.002  743 11131
X  1846     1001L  34023.00  51785.002 1114 14841
....
X  1846     9991L  34027.00  51353.002    1  4321
X  1846     9991L  34027.00  51353.002  433  8641
X  1846     9991L  34027.00  51353.002  865 12961
X  1846     9991L  34027.00  51353.002 1297 17281
X  1846    10001L  33593.00  51053.001    1  4321
X  1846    10001L  33593.00  51053.001  433  8641
X  1846    10001L  33593.00  51053.001  865 12961
X  1846    10001L  33593.00  51053.001 1297 17281
.....
```

**Result:**

```
1846   21 33599 51209
1846   22 34031 52085
...
1846  100 34023 51785
...
1846  999 34027 51353
1846 1000 33593 51053
...
```

I want for 21 for example two space before 21 to let this 1 be in the same column as the 0 in 1000:

```
  21
1000
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: You actually don't have to past the whole table if it's that long. First three or four lines would be sufficient. See also [StackOverflow help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) about Markdown rules it uses.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will take care in the future

Answer (score 2):

You can use awk (at least I tested with gnu awk) like this:

```
awk -v FS="([ .]+|1L)" '{printf("%4d %4d %5d %5d\n", $2, $3, $5, $7)}'  your_file
```

It uses `1L` and `.` as additional field delimiters, thus we get the decimal parts `.00` as fields (that we ignore). And the `1L` is also ingored, by this delimiter setting.

If you dont like the awk solution, you could also use the tool `cut` and provide the desired output chars with the `-c` option:

```
cut -c 4-8,12-15,19-24,29-34 your_file
```

Comment: @H.R When you want to use cut, look at the longest numbers and thing what offsets you want. I wanted to `cut -c4-15,18-24,28-34` including some spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the input looks *exactly* as presented in the question, left-filled with spaces and not tabs, there is a quick and dirty [`colrm`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/colrm.1.html) approach:

```
$ cat input.txt | colrm 35 | colrm 25 27 | colrm 16 18 | colrm 1 3
1846      21 33599  51209
1846      21 33599  51209
1846      21 33599  51209
1846      21 33599  51209
...
```

Note that I'd not recommend using this if you want you data processing to be robust and reliable. Maybe you should consider using more appropriate tool than Bash.

Comment: @H.R: BTW, the `cut` approach in Lars's answer seems to be superior, as it doesn't lead to spawning multiple processes for that simple task.